# How to update a state of a specific index in array

Tags: reactjs

So I am practicing React and wanted to display a "Arya's kill list" ], I wanted to make it possible to update it. So in my ToKill component when you double click on a character it shows inputs with values. But it is not possible to update them.

I wrote a function in my main App component it looks like this :

```
    const toKillPpl = { ...this.state.toKill }
    toKillPpl[index] = updatedToKill
      this.setState({ toKillPpl })
  }
```

next I pass it to ToKillList component with a state :

```
            doubleClick = {this.doubleClickHandler}
            deleteToKill = {this.deleteToKillHandler}
            backBtn = {this.backBtnHandler} 
            state = {this.state}
            toKillState = {this.state.toKill}
            update = {this.toKillUpdate}
          />
```

in my ToKillList component I map over my state and I pass this function with a state of a person (toKillPerson) :

```
const ToKillList = (props) => props.state.toKill.map((toKill, index) => {
  return <ToKill 
    double ={() => props.doubleClick(index)}
    formDouble={toKill.formDouble}
    click ={() => props.deleteToKill(index)}
    backBtn ={() => props.backBtn(index)}
    key={index + toKill.name}
    index={index}
    toKillPerson ={props.toKillState[index]}
    update={props.update}
    name={toKill.name}
    cause={toKill.cause}
    img={toKill.img} 
    />
  })
```

Finally in my ToKill component I write a function "handleChange" :

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const updatedToKill = {
        ...this.props.toKillPerson,
        [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
    }
    this.props.update(this.props.index, updatedToKill)
}
```

And here are inputs:

```
<input 
      type="text"
      name="name"
      className="hero-name" 
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      value={this.props.name}
   />
<input 
      type="text"
      name="img"
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      value={this.props.img}
   />
<input 
      type="text"
      name="cause"
      className="hero-cause" 
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
      value={this.props.cause}
   />
```

And it doesn't work. Is it a good approach, or I messed it up completely?

In case I wasn't clear here is a github repo: https://github.com/jakubmas/Aryas-Kill-List

Answer (score 1):

Two correction in update method in your code.

1) You are not correctly copying over object,

`const toKillPpl = { ...this.state.toKill }`

This creates a shallow copy, you need deep cloning for this. You could either use JSON.strigify or lodash deepClone method.

2) You are not updating `toKill` state which is being passed to child components.

Here is the updated method:

```
  toKillUpdate = (index, updatedToKill) => {
    // const toKillPpl = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.toKill)); // use this
    const toKillPpl = _.cloneDeep(this.state.toKill); // or this
    toKillPpl[index] = updatedToKill;
    this.setState({ toKill: toKillPpl });
  };
```

Here is the working [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-margulis-tk0oz)

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got your point but when I implemented it, it just crashes. The div that I tried to update shows only delete button and text with one letter changed.

Comment: This is because of key not being correctly passed in `ToKill` component. Just pass `key={index}` or use any library to provide key to identify row uniquely. Here is [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-margulis-tk0oz)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is that you could import `immutability-helper` (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper), and use it to update `state.toKill` without mutating it:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

// Assuming 'updateToKill' input is an object...
handleUpdate = (index, updatedToKill) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        toKill: update(prevState.toKill, {
            [index]: {
                $set: updatedToKill,
            },
        }),
    }));
};
```